# How to get list of users who didn't place on order in the past year

Tags: magento-1.7, promotions

We want to get a list of users who didn't place an order in the past year, so we can send out a promo code for them. What is the best way to get this list from magento? I am not interested in just code solutions, if you know any premium extensions that have this feature  it would be great (I couldn't find any)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no extension for this.

I can't code the entire extension but you can do an observer for the event customer_login and inside the observer class check if there is any order for the customer and if not, generate a one use coupon and send it via email.

You will have also to store this action in a DB table or in any persistent way you like to avoid sending twice an email to the same customer.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357225/magento-check-for-customers-first-order) you can see a way to check if a customer placed an order or not.

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());

if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && (!$orders->getSize()))
{ 
    // has never placed an order 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a report - customers and order quantities. Specify the dates to cover the last year, run the report, export CSV file.

You can then edit this file in a normal spreadsheet program, get the list of email addresses, add them to a list in your mailer software, then send out a generic coupon for them.

This will get the job done. Time can be invested in the sales email rather than writing yet more code.

If you did want to write a module then you could iterate through all of the customers as per a 'cron' schedule and email them if they have not been to spend money at your store. You will need to keep track of whom has been sent an email so you may need to add a customer attribute and update that when customers have been emailed.

That said, you have the basis of an idea for a neat module!

Comment: This is what I was looking for, somehow to export this data. However, when I went to Report -> Customers -> Customers by number of orders and generate the report, I only get the top 5 customers and this is not what we are looking for.